# Open MQ broker won't start

Tags: glassfish, jms, mq, broker, openmq

We're running Glassfish 4.1.1 (Payara) with mq 5.1.1. It's a HA setup with load balancer and cluster.

Glassfish is running ok. Problem is that MQ won't start.

I think that a remote MQ is starting. I can do imqcmd list bkr -b  and I get successful results.

However when I do imqcmd list bkr (or imqcmd list jmx, *without* -b hostname) I get:

---

```
Host         Primary Port
-------------------------
localhost    7676

WARNING: [C4003]: Error occurred on connection creation [localhost:7676]. - cause: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Error while connecting to the broker on host 'localhost' and port '7676'.
```

I'd like to get rid of the error, and see my network ip instead of localhost.

Also GF server.log gives this:

```
[2017-04-12T11:54:46.516-0400] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [rardeployment.start_failed] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1492012486516] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RAR6035 : Resource adapter start failed.
javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAdapterInternalException: MQJMSRA_RA4001: start:Aborting:Exception starting EMBEDDED broker=Broker failed to start
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.jms.system.ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.startResourceAdapter(ActiveJmsResourceAdapter.java:557)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ActiveOutboundResourceAdapter.init(ActiveOutboundResourceAdapter.java:130)

...

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Broker failed to start
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsclient.runtime.impl.BrokerInstanceImpl.start(BrokerInstanceImpl.java:205)
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.blc.EmbeddedBrokerRunner.start(EmbeddedBrokerRunner.java:331)
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.blc.LifecycleManagedBroker.start(LifecycleManagedBroker.java:457)
        ... 92 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: [B3297]: Unable to make directory <mydirectory>/imq/instances/imqbroker/etc
        at com.sun.messaging.jmq.jmsserver.Broker.initializePasswdFile(Broker.java:376)
```

I'm wondering where the directory that it is unable to make is configured.

I've been debugging this for days. I need to know where to configure the ip for the embedded broker. I also need to know where to set up the jmxrmi url.

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem. We had a broken symlink to the openmq application directory, within the Glassfish application directory. On domain startup, Glassfish could not find mq and therefore could not start the embedded broker. Once we fixed the symlink, the embedded broker started up on glassfish domain startup (asadmin start-domain).

I knew the embedded broker was not starting because the "imq" folder was not being created in <domaindir>/

Check for those broken symlinks!!

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer, even if it's yours, so that people know the solution has been found.